# Beaker can't use any image (decompression fails)

Tags: testing, puppet

I am super new to Beaker. I am following the [beaker quick tasks guide](https://github.com/puppetlabs/beaker/blob/master/docs/tutorials/quick_start_rake_tasks.md) but when I try to run the test with `rake beaker_quickstart:run_test` it always fails, rendering this error:

```
Failed: errored in CLI.initialize_network_manager
#<RuntimeError: Failed to exec 'vagrant up'. Error was The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
```

file you're trying to add is not corrupted and try again. The
output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

```
x Vagrantfile
x box.ovf
x metadata.json
x packer-debian-7.8-x86_64-virtualbox-vagrant-nocm-1457462804-disk1.vmdk: gzip decompression failed
bsdtar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
>
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/beaker-3.19.0/bin/beaker:9
```

It is using the default files, no funky config from my side. I tried using different images, but it always fails there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using Test-Kitchen instead? It is actually significantly more popular than Beaker.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I thought `test-kitchen` was just for Chef, whereas `beaker` was the Puppet equivalent. Is that not the case?

Comment: Test-Kitchen works with basically everything people use on both the provisioning side and the validation provider side.